# MYSQL View with LEFT JOIN return all possible combinations

Tags: mysql, join, view

I am working on a view that joins multiple table. The data will be entered on separate table based on RepairID. The view will gather the data that is linking to the RepairID. My problem is after I enter the data, the view will show all the probability of the records output. Below are my code of view:

```
SELECT 
    `new`.`SRPartsID` AS `SRPartsID`,
    `new`.`RepairID` AS `RepairID`,
    `new`.`SRNo` AS `SRNo`,
    `new`.`DateReceived` AS `DateReceived`,
    `new`.`ShipmentDate` AS `ShipmentDate`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugActionTaken` AS `FirstDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugComponentLocation` AS `FirstDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugActionTaken` AS `SecondDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugComponentLocation` AS `SecondDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugActionTaken` AS `ThirdDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugComponentLocation` AS `ThirdDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctActionTaken` AS `FirstFctActionTaken`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctComponentLocation` AS `FirstFctComponentLocation`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctActionTaken` AS `SecondFctActionTaken`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctComponentLocation` AS `SecondFctComponentLocation`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctActionTaken` AS `ThirdFctActionTaken`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctComponentLocation` AS `ThirdFctComponentLocation`
FROM
    ((((((`tbsrparts_new` `new`
    LEFT JOIN `tb1stdebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb1stdebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb2nddebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb2nddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb3rddebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb3rddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb1stfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb1stfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb2ndfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb2ndfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb3rdfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb3rdfct`.`RepairID`)))
ORDER BY `new`.`SRPartsID` DESC
```

This is my table structure

**tbsrparts_new**

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|             Field             |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SRPartsID                     | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                      | varchar(200)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SRNo                          | varchar(200)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DateReceived                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ShipmentDate                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb1stdebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb2nddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                     | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb3rddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb1stfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb2ndfct**

```
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb3rdfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my sample data inserted to the db

**tbsrparts_new**

```
+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| SRPartsID | RepairID | SRNo  | DateReceived | ShipmentDate |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|     26050 |    26041 | test2 | 02,July,2015 | Pending      |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

**tb1stdebug**

```
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| FirstDebugID | RepairID | FirstDebugTestingErrorCode | FirstDebugActionTaken | FirstDebugComponentLocation |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|        26048 |    26041 | T00111                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
|        26049 |    26041 | T02222                     | Retest                | -                           |
|        26053 |    26041 | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**tb2nddebug**

```
+---------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
| SecondDebugID | RepairID | SecondDebugTestingErrorCode | SecondDebugActionTaken | SecondDebugComponentLocation |
+---------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
|            12 |    26041 | T03333                      | Touch Up               | -                            |
|            13 |    26041 | T04444                      | Retest                 | -                            |
|            14 |    26041 | T08888                      | Touch Up               | -                            |
+---------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
```

**tb3rddebug**

```
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| ThirdDebugID | RepairID | ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode | ThirdDebugActionTaken | ThirdDebugComponentLocation |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|           12 |    26041 | T03333                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
|           13 |    26041 | T04444                     | Retest                | -                           |
|           14 |    26041 | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**tb1stfct**

```
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| FirstFctID | RepairID | FirstFctTestingErrorCode | FirstFctActionTaken | FirstFctComponentLocation |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|      26052 |    26041 | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

**tb2ndfct**

```
+-------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| SecondFctID | RepairID | SecondFctTestingErrorCode | SecondFctActionTaken | SecondFctComponentLocation |
+-------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
|           9 |    26041 | T08888                    | Touch Up             | -                          |
|          10 |    26041 | T88889                    | Retest               | -                          |
+-------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

**tb3rdfct**

```
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| ThirdFctID | RepairID | ThirdFctTestingErrorCode | ThirdFctActionTaken | ThirdFctComponentLocation |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|          7 |    26041 | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

The output on the view shows all the probability of the combination since some of the table has more than 1 records that referring to the same RepairID. Below are the output in image format. I cant paste the table because it reached the maximum characters.

[image: Output]

I have also create the schema on sqlfiddle with my view query : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d155d/7

Since it returning too many rows, its hard for me to analyse the data. I am not sure how to reduce the number of rows. I don't want it to show all the possible combination. Can anyone help me??

This is the output i want

```
    +-------+---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| SRNo  | DateReceived  | ShipmentDate | FirstDebugTestingErrorCode | FirstDebugActionTaken | FirstDebugComponentLocation | SecondDebugTestingErrorCode | SecondDebugActionTaken | SecondDebugComponentLocation | ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode | ThirdDebugActionTaken | ThirdDebugComponentLocation | FirstFctTestingErrorCode | FirstFctActionTaken | FirstFctComponentLocation | SecondFctTestingErrorCode | SecondFctActionTaken | SecondFctComponentLocation | ThirdFctTestingErrorCode | ThirdFctActionTaken | ThirdFctComponentLocation |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| test2 | 2, July, 2015 | Pending      | T00111                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T03333                      | Touch Up               | -                            | T05555                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         | T08888                    | Touch Up             | -                          | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
| test2 | 2, July, 2015 | Pending      | T02222                     | Retest                | -                           | T04444                      | Retest                 | -                            | T06666                     | Retest                | -                           | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         | T08889                    | Retest               | -                          | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
| test2 | 2, July, 2015 | Pending      | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T08888                      | Touch Up               | -                            | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         | T08889                    | Retest               | -                          | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: And what is the output that you want?

Comment: The output is right. In the example you have, there are 7 tables with the following count per table, for the same Repair_ID: (1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2,1). If you multiply the numbers, you will get (54), which is the same number of row you got in the result.

Comment: Hi @oNare I have edited the question with the output i want. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Hi @JehadKeriaki, I have edited the question with the output i want. Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you mentioned, you may run the following query. Basically, it is the same as yours with `GROUP BY` added:

```
SELECT 
    `new`.`SRPartsID` AS `SRPartsID`,
    `new`.`RepairID` AS `RepairID`,
    `new`.`SRNo` AS `SRNo`,
    `new`.`DateReceived` AS `DateReceived`,
    `new`.`ShipmentDate` AS `ShipmentDate`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugActionTaken` AS `FirstDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugComponentLocation` AS `FirstDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugActionTaken` AS `SecondDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugComponentLocation` AS `SecondDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugActionTaken` AS `ThirdDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugComponentLocation` AS `ThirdDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctActionTaken` AS `FirstFctActionTaken`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctComponentLocation` AS `FirstFctComponentLocation`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctActionTaken` AS `SecondFctActionTaken`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctComponentLocation` AS `SecondFctComponentLocation`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctActionTaken` AS `ThirdFctActionTaken`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctComponentLocation` AS `ThirdFctComponentLocation`
FROM
    ((((((`tbsrparts_new` `new`
    LEFT JOIN `tb1stdebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb1stdebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb2nddebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb2nddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb3rddebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb3rddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb1stfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb1stfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb2ndfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb2ndfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb3rdfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb3rdfct`.`RepairID`)))
GROUP BY SRNo, DateReceived, FirstDebugTestingErrorCode
ORDER BY `new`.`SRPartsID` DESC
```

However, this might be logically wrong, as you cannot guarantee what info from other fields/tables would show from the fields that are not in the `group by` part of the query.

Comment: I did try this, but it only can works on works for table tb1stdebug, for other tables, it selects same data. Is this can be done by using union?

Comment: When a "left join" introduces multiple lines because one field happen to have multiple values for a given id : GROUP BY: only shows the first line. How can we make it show "all the values for the problematic field, concatenated" in that field, instead of just the first occurence?